# Is it a bad thing to ask for an extra recommendation letter?

Tags: recommendation-letter

My professors have written and submitted the letter to all schools that I applied. However, I was thinking about applying to 1 more school. Does it reflect badly on me?

Comment: Why would you think it would? An extra letter is a minimal undertaking. The first one is the hardest.

Comment: Ask. The professors can probably use the same letters, or can edit them easily. Helping you in the next stage of your career is part of their job.